# How to change the string value in multiple places?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Let's say I have a string that I used to set a value for a few `Kivy` widgets. How could I make all the widgets react to the change of that string?
I could make that string a property for each widget, but if I change the property of one widget, the others with the same property aren't going to change accordingly.

The behaviour I want is like list referencing:

```
st = ["1"]
st1 = st
st.append("2")
print(st1, st)  # output: ['1', '2'] ['1', '2']
```

As you can see, when I change the list `st`, the list `st1` also changes. That's because `st1` is a reference to a list. How can I make this behaviour apply to strings? Possibly using `Kivy`, if Python's standard library does not have a way to achieve what I want

And here is the demonstration in Kivy:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class TestApp(App):
    def change_text(self, bt):
        self.string += "!"
        print(self.string)

    def build(self):
        self.string = "Hello"
        lb = Label(text = self.string)
        bt = Button(on_press = self.change_text)
        tx = TextInput(text = self.string)
        bl = BoxLayout()
        bl.add_widget(lb)
        bl.add_widget(tx)
        bl.add_widget(bt)
        return bl

TestApp().run()
```

So when the button gets pressed, the App's attribute `string` changes, but I want that change to be reflected on the widgets to left(`Label`, `TextInput`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In kivy you can use properties for that (not to be confused with python properties, which are a complete different thing). In kv language you should be able to do the following:

```
MainWidget:
    id: "main"
    mystring: "asdf"

    widget1:
        content: main.mystring
    widget2:
        content: main.mystring
    ...
```

Read more in the kivy documentation for [properties](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html).